# What clustering I should use to cluster colleges into similar comparison groups?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am new to clustering and don't know how to pick which clustering method to apply.

My data is about 1303 colleges/universities and 35 variables such as application received/accepted, students combined SAT score, graduation rate...etc

Here's [description of my data](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/usnews.txt) and the [dataset](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/usnews3.dat.txt)

Which clustering would be better when I want to cluster colleges into similar comparison groups, say the graduation rate?

I tried the complete linkage method --- `hclust` in r but the plot of it just a mess at the bottom...

Any suggestions that I can do a better clustering in r with my dataset ? Thanks !

Comment: I think this is the same data, but in CSV format, much easier to read into `R`: http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/usnews.dat.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a good distance / dissimilarity metric will make a significant difference in the result of `hclust`. I'm guessing that by default it chooses some Euclidean distance metric, meaning each of the variables are weighted equally in their feature space.

A better idea would be to come up with a dissimilarity function yourself: A function that given two universities will come up with a dissimilarity between them. You can integrate your understanding of the metrics in the data and any other a priori information with this function, and then calculate the dissimilarity matrix `d` (parameter of `hdist`) yourself.

If you want to focus on the graduation rate, then your dissimilarity function could in the most extreme case only yield this difference. However, it gets more interesting if you for example think that both graduation rate and some other factor is important, and then make a dissimilarity function that takes both into account, but gives the graduation rate a heavier weighting.

Then the hierarchical clustering results should better extract interesting patterns from the data.

Comment: So when I look for dissimilarity, to my understanding, I need to find the furthest apart points, in my case , consider the two graduation rate that has max difference? since I want to cluster the universities by graduation rate...or I do need to include other variables in the data ? Thanks!

Comment: Have expanded my answer: That's the thing with hierarchical clustering on dissimilarity, the analyst can design a function that only focuses on a subset of the features (because they're the most important for a specific study) or takes all of them into account.

Comment: Hey thanks for the details ! And I tried different ways to clustering  and build the plots. To me it looks like a classification tree is better.